# Periodical tasks in Delphi app

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer, thread-safety, scheduled-tasks

I'm developing an application that should perform certain sql queries in different MSSQL servers after specified intervals. My thoughts are about make an array of threads and in each thread run timer in which task will run. Does it really needs to make each thread for each timer, or should I just distinguish one timer for each task (whatever timer will produce thread)? Any thoughts about implementation?

Thanks a lot, guys!

Comment: The Sql Server has this funcionality, Are you trying using [Sql server Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175138%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)? you can schedule a job to run automatically .

Comment: There are another subtasks that application needs to run, not only SQL query.

Comment: A Sql job can do much more that execute SQL querys, you can run stored procedures, execute backups and even execute external apps.

Comment: Another option is to use the system's scheduled task mechanism

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Scheduled tasks doesn't fit for my requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that you need to have one thread per task. It would probably suffice to create one timer per task. If a timer fires whilst another task is running then the second task will have to queue up but it doesn't sound like that will be a great problem.

If you are going to use a Delphi `TTimer` to do this you'll need to make sure that your service has a message queue and runs a message loop on that queue. You may wish to run that message queue on a separate thread but if you do make sure that the `TTimer` objects are created on that thread so that they are associated with the right message queue.

---

You ask in the comments how to run a message loop in a thread. The following code should suffice:

```
repeat
  try
    Application.HandleMessage;
  except
    Application.HandleException(Application);
  end;
until Terminated;//this is the Terminated property of the thread
```

This will give you all the bells and whistles of the Delphi message loop. If you want a very standard message loop you can use this:

```
procedure PerformThreadLoop;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  repeat
    Try
      while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do begin
        TranslateMessage(Msg);
        DispatchMessage(Msg);
      end;
      WaitMessage;
    Except
      Application.HandleException(Self);
    End;
  until Terminated;//this is the Terminated property of the thread
end;
```

If all you want is to pump `WM_TIMER` messages both will work but I personally would be inclined to go with the second option, the raw Win32 API version.

Comment: Why I need message queue? Why I just can't create timers with `OnTimer` events?

Comment: @kseen Because `TTimer` is a wrapper to Win32 `SetTimer` which in turn operates by posting WM_TIMER messages to the thread of the hidden window associated with the timer. You can use other Windows timers if you want to avoid a message queue.

Comment: Could you please point me at other Windows timers that doesn't require the message queue?

Comment: There's `CreateWaitableTimer` and `CreateTimerQueue`. I confess I've never heard of the latter. Note that a thread with a message pump is pretty benign and easy to setup. I wouldn't be too worried about doing it that way. It's certainly most convenient to be able to use `TTimer`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm not so clear about message queue, so could you please provide me some sample?

Comment: I think the whole message loop thing is confusing the OP. Perhaps this will help:  If you have a regular GUI app, the message loop is already there. But if you're building a console app, service, etc., you wouldn't normally have a message loop, hence David's suggestion that you add one so that the timers will fire.

Comment: @chris you might not want the timers to fire in the gui thread of this app